# In Chrome, mouse 4 and 5 don't navigate "back" and "forward"

Tags: windows, macos, google-chrome

I just setup my Mac Mini to do some stuff and I'm noticing that when I'm in Chrome and push mouse 4 or mouse 5 Chrome doesn't navigate forward or back as it does on Windows.  Is there anyway to get the Windows Behavior on my Mac?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OS X doesn't seem to natively support more than three mouse buttons. However, you can use a mouse prefpane such as [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) to bind mouse4 and mouse5 to cmd + [ and cmd + ] - which are shortcuts to go forward and back in web browsers - as seen in this [image](http://plentycom.jp/en/images/l/win_btn.jpg), which will give you the Windows-like behavior you're looking for.

Comment: $20 to remap buttons

Comment: Worth noting that Smooze does this functionality as well for $5. It also has smooth scrolling but that can be disabled.